# import .PDF 3d file

Tags: import

I have a .PDF file containing a 3d model of a building, I want to open this in blender, I found this [plugin](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/AI_PDF_SVG) but everytime I try to open the PDF it says unknown file.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to extract a 3D model directly from inside a pdf, that is way too involved and unique data. You may be able to extract 2D vector information at best. You may need access to the source file